# Touchpad not working after login in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

At some point my touchpad stopped working on Lenovo x220 under Ubuntu 11.10, after login.

I have found two possible solutions for that online, but neither of them work.

[First](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad),
`gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled true`
and a [second one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74982/touchpad-stops-working-after-login-on-a-lenovo-t60),
`xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Off" 8 0`

After looking more carefully into xinput I have realized that 
`xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"` outputs:

> Device Enabled (132): 0

This field seems to be stuck to zero, because trying to set it back to 1 by:
`xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 8 1`
doesn't seem to have any effect, e.g. I still have:

> Device Enabled (132):  0

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Could you try `synclient TouchpadOff=0`?

Comment: I just tried that and I get a very strange behaviour (after a few seconds it comes back to 1, also the touchpad is not working during these seconds):

$ synclient TouchpadOff=0
$ synclient -l | grep Touch
    TouchpadOff             = 0

$ synclient -l | grep Touch
    TouchpadOff             = 0

$ synclient -l | grep Touch
    TouchpadOff             = 1

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Comment: please try to explain to the best of your ability the command lines you used as answer. also, short answers are non-adviseable, as an explanation of the steps, even if a small one, is seen as healthy behaviour twards future readers.

Comment: this worked ! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad.touchpad-enabled` to true with `dconf-editor`.

([Source](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/11/is-your-laptop-touchpad-not-working.html))

Comment: Great, this finally worked!! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MariaMateescu If it worked, [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) by clicking on the tick to the left of the answer.

Comment: If you don't have a mouse, run `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled true`. It does the exact same thing via the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Having absolutely the same configuration (Lenovo x220/Ubuntu 11.10) and experiencing the same issue, I've done the following:
I checked out what goes out to standard output when i press FN+F8 (Touchpad off shortcut) using:

```
xinput --watch-props 11
```

(11 is my device id from "xinput list" command)

**What i should get when disabling touchpad:**

```
Property 'Synaptics Off' changed.
Synaptics Off (286):    1
Property 'Device Enabled' changed.
    Device Enabled (132):   0
Property 'Device Enabled' changed.
    Device Enabled (132):   0
```

**What i got this time:**

```
Property 'Synaptics Off' changed.
Synaptics Off (286):    1
Property 'Device Enabled' changed.
    Device Enabled (132):   1
Property 'Device Enabled' changed.
    Device Enabled (132):   1
```

So it's a list of mutual excluded parameters.

**What i did:**

```
xinput --set-prop 11 'Synaptics Off' 0
```

And everything worked fine after that, even after logout.